# Ruby - how to thread across cores / processors

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets

Im (re)writing a socket server in ruby in hopes of simplifying it. Reading about ruby sockets I ran across a [site](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_threads.html) that says multithreaded ruby apps only use one core / processor in a machine.

Questions:

1. Is this accurate?
2. Do I care? Each thread in this server will potentially run for several minutes and there will be lots of them. Is the OS (CentOS 6.5) smart enough to share the load?
3. Is this any different from threading in C++? (language of the current socket server) IE do **pthreads** use multiple cores automatically?
4. What if I **fork** instead of **thread**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CRuby has a [global interpreter lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock), so it cannot run threads in parallel. Jruby and some other implementations can do it, but CRuby will never run any kind of code in parallel. This means that, no matter how smart your OS is, it can never share the load.

This is different in threading in C++. pthreads create real OS threads, and the kernal's scheduler will run them on multiple cores at the same time. Technically Ruby uses pthreads as well, but the GIL prevents them from running in parallel.

Fork creates a new process, and your OS's scheduler will almost certainly be smart enough to run it on a separate core. If you need parallelism in Ruby, either use an implementation without a GIL, or use fork.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very nice gem called [parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) which allows data processing with parallel threads or multiple processes by forking (work around GIL of current CRuby implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Due to [GIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) in YARV, ruby is not thread friendly. If you want to write multithreaded ruby use jruby or rubinius. It would be even better to use a functional language with actor model such as Erlang or Elixir and let the Virtual Machine handle the threads and you only manage the Erlang processes.

Comment: MRI doesn't have a GIL. YARV has a GIL, but MRI doesn't need one. MRI has green threads which are scheduled by the interpreter itself. The interpreter is incapable of scheduling two threads at the same time anyway, so there's no need to lock anything.

Answer (score 0):

### Threading

If you're going to want multi-core threading, you need to use an interpreter that actively uses multiple cores. MRI Ruby as of 2.1.3 is still only single-core; JRuby and Rubinius allow access to multiple cores.

### Threading Alternatives

Alternatives to changing your interpreter include:

- [DRb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/drb/rdoc/DRb.html) with multiple Ruby processes.
- A queuing system with multiple workers.
- Socket programming with multiple interpreters.
- Forking processes, if the underlying platform supports the fork(2) system call.