# Do Ruby threads run on multiple cores?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I've read that Ruby code (CRuby/YARV) only "runs" on a single processor core, but something is not clear yet:

I understand that the GIL prevents threads from running concurrently and that in recent Ruby versions threads are scheduled by the operating system.

Couldn't a thread possibly be "**placed**" on core 1 and the other on core 2, even if they're not actually running at the same time?

Just trying to understand if the OS scheduler actually puts all Ruby threads on a single core. Thanks!

Edit: Another answer mentions that C++ uses pthreads and those are scheduled across cores, and that Ruby uses the same. I guess that's what I was looking for, but since most answers seem to equate not running threads in parallel with never running on multiple cores, I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby - how to thread across cores / processors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579532/ruby-how-to-thread-across-cores-processors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, we have to clearly distinguish between "Ruby Threads" and "Ruby Threads as implemented by YARV". Ruby Threads make no guarantees how they are scheduled. They might be scheduled concurrently, they might not. They might be scheduled on multiple CPUs, they might not. They might be implemented as native platform threads, they might be implemented as green threads, they might be implemented as something else.

YARV implements Ruby Threads as native platform threads (e.g. pthreads on POSIX and Windows threads on Windows). However, unlike other Ruby implementations which use native platform threads (e.g. JRuby, IronRuby, Rubinius), YARV has a Giant VM Lock (GVL) which prevents two threads to enter the YARV bytecode interpreter at the same time. This makes it effectively impossible to run Ruby code in multiple threads at the same time.

Note however, that the GVL only protects the YARV interpreter and runtime. This means that, for example, multiple threads can execute *C* code at the same time, and at the same time as another thread executed Ruby code. It just means that no two threads can execute Ruby code at the same time on YARV.

Note also that in recent versions of YARV, the "Giant" VM Lock is becoming ever smaller. Sections of code are moved out from under the lock, and the lock itself is broken down in smaller, more fine-grained locks. That is a very long process, but it means that in the future more and more Ruby code will be able to run in parallel on YARV.

But, all of this has nothing to do with how the platform schedules the threads. Many platforms have some sort of heuristics for thread affinity to CPU cores, e.g they may try to schedule the same thread to the same core, under the assumption that its working set is still in that core's cache, or they may try to identify threads that operate on shared data, and schedule those threads to the same CPU and so on. Therefore, it is hard to impossible to predict how and where a thread will be scheduled.

Many platforms also provide a way to influence this CPU affinity, e.g. on Linux and Windows, you can set a thread to only be scheduled on one specific or a set of specific cores. However, YARV does not do that by default. (In fact, on some platforms influencing CPU affinity requires elevated privileges, so it would mean that YARV would have to run with elevated privileges, which is *not* a good idea.)

So, in short: yes, depending on the platform, the hardware, and the environment, YARV threads *may* and probably *will* be scheduled on different cores. But, they won't be able to take advantage of that fact, i.e. they won't be able to run faster than on a single core (at least when running Ruby code).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly the distinction I was looking for. Too often I've heard that Ruby (YARV) "only runs on a single core". I think it's important to know how it actually works (regardless of taking advantage of it), since soon it will be getting new abstractions for concurrency, with Guilds etc. I suspect we'll be seeing a lot more usage of concurrency once those arrive. Cheers.